# How do I straighten a tilting Spider Plant without repotting it?

Tags: houseplants, repotting

I recently repotted a spider plant, but it has recently started sagging, probably due to its weight and lack of support in the soil. I want to straighten it back up, but I would like to do this without repotting if possible. The spider plant has multiple stems and they're all tilting in the same direction.

Here's a picture of the plant in its current state. You can notice that all of the leaves fall to the back.

[image: The spider plant]

Answer (score 6):

One of the most beautiful spider plants I've ever seen!  And that is saying something because in my day every hippie had a spider plant, even those in a store aren't as beautiful.  Good job!

If you have just repotted this plant then this is easy.  On the side you want the plant to move to be more vertical, simply press the soil down on that side.  Help your plant by holding the base and all the leaves in one hand while the other presses down the soil.  The soil in your pot should be firmed down anyway.  When your plant is upright, then gently press the rest of the soil down in the pot.  I've even pulled newly planted plants upward slightly to firm the soil down on the side it is leaning towards and shake and poke soil under the roots of the far side.  In fact this is probably best if you weren't firming the soil while repotting.  Plants are tough.  This will not hurt your plant.

If you were to just firm all the soil, water, your plant would eventually straighten quite nicely as it grows toward the light.  But I would simply slightly pull the plant (is that one plant or two?) upwards, shake it gently or poke to get the soil to fill the pocket on the side it is leaning to be filled with more soil, then firmed under your plant when it is in the position you want.  If this is one plant (could easily be made into two but don't) simply grab the lower parts in two hands and upright into position.  Get into the soil to fill soil into the pocket left (right side?)and firm that soil below the roots to ensure the position.  What ever management practices you have been using continue.  Very happy plant!  Kudos!!

Comment: It IS beautiful with no brown tips! I'd also suggest (beside the excellent advice stormy gave) to face the side opposite the one with leaves next to the window. It won't take long till the leaves reach toward the light, helping straighten the plant.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments! I tried touching the soil but it's quite firm already, so it seems like it won't budge. I also noticed that on the opposite side than the one the plant is leaning towards, some of the fat roots are sticking out. Is this a side-effect of the tipping or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Plants just are not as delicate as most people imagine. If you grabbed that plant and 'gently' pulled up upwards, an inch? shook the pot of soil, the hole left on the side it is leaning will fill with soil.  I'd use my fingers to firm that soil beneath your plant, put the plant back into the soil, and water.  Cover any exposed roots with soil.  By now, your plant has already put out new roots, to straighten it now would definitely cause breakage.  It is no big deal.  Breakage of roots actually generates root growth.

Comment: When this happens you'll not see much growth topside.  No big deal.  If you left this plant alone, it would most certainly grow straight, with a bit of a crook at the bottom of the plant, maybe.  Turn your pot now and then towards the light will help a more symmetrical plant.

Comment: ...and looking closely at your picture, this guy looks straight enough.  In fact, one side goes to the left the other to the right.  I would just leave your plant alone.  I truly can not see any leaning...